# formulas in another column that reference spill range not updating when sheet is recalculated

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I have a a column that is a spill range that uses the filter and sort_by formulas.  This spill range is dynamic and I have an IF statement that references the spill range but upon recalculation of the sheet the IF statement doesn't recalculate past the length of the old spill range. Here is the spill range formula:

```
    =SORTBY(FILTER('Loss Template'!$E:$E, ('Loss Template'!$A:$A=TEXT($B$2,"0"))*('Loss 
Template'!$F:$F<=$J$7)*('Loss Template'!$F:$F>=$H$7)*('Loss Template'!$H:$H>2000)*('Loss 
Template'!$M:$M=5),""),FILTER('Loss Template'!$M:$M, ('Loss Template'!$A:$A=TEXT($B$2,"0"))* 
('Loss Template'!$F:$F<=$J$7)*('Loss Template'!$F:$F>=$H$7)*('Loss Template'!$H:$H>2000)* 
('Loss Template'!$M:$M=5),""),1,FILTER('Loss Template'!$H:$H, ('Loss 
Template'!$A:$A=TEXT($B$2,"0"))*('Loss Template'!$F:$F<=$J$7)*('Loss Template'!$F:$F>=$H$7)* 
('Loss Template'!$H:$H>2000)*('Loss Template'!$M:$M=5),""),1)
```

Here is the IF statement:

`=IF($G10<>"",IF(XLOOKUP($G10,'Loss Template'!E:E,'Loss Template'!G:G,,0)="Closed","F","O"),"")`

I found out if I Find and Replace "=" with "=".

Should I code a workaround in my update_macro doing this? Or how can improve these formulas?

Comment: Difficult to say, since we don't have sample data to justify the commands been used ,, if possible plz [edit] the post and share some sample data or file on cloud.

Comment: Since XLOOKUP and spill ranges are so new in Excel, I suspect you have found a bug whereby the sheet recalculation isn't being triggered when it should be. In which case, report it to Microsoft and use your workaround till it's fixed. However, as already suggested by @Rajesh S, to enable us to understand your precise scenario better, you should edit your post to include the minimum example data that will reproduce the issue.

Comment: which part of the if statement is referencing the spilled range? It looks like excel wants to reference a spilled range with a `#` sign, so if your spilled range starts at A2, then the reference would be `A2#`

Answer (score 0):

Using the Spill operator in the if statements (#).

`=IF($G10#<>"",IF(XLOOKUP($G10#,'Loss Template'!E:E,'Loss Template'!G:G,,0)="Closed","F","O"),"")`

Thanks for the help guys!